# What would cause Fontawesome icons to load from CSS but not with <i> tags?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

WordPress site running on Cloudflare with a custom theme, FA is being called in the header (not functions.php) like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

This used to work

```
<i class="icon-search"></i>
```

but seems to have ceased functioning after the most recent WP update & I've noticed that it no longer works on other sites when I used a workaround by calling the icons from CSS instead.

The example given is being called from searchform.php but it doesn't work in the WYSIWYG either.  Most of the BS glyphicons seem to work alright, though.

The site is https but like I mentioned it worked fine previously, so I'm inclined to think it's due to a WP update.

What does the collective say?

Comment: What is icon-search? A class from your css? Because If you want to use icons from FA, you have to do it like this <i class="fa fa-icon name""></i>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In FontAwesome 3.* you had to use (http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icon/search/)

```
<i class="icon-search"></i> icon-search
```

Now it seems your Wordpress website has the upgraded version of FontAwesome 4.* where you should use it like: (http://fontawesome.io/icon/search/)

```
<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Ok I feel like a dolt, now - I swear I thought I'd tried that already but apparently I can't even this week.  Thanks much, marcanuy!

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome doesn't use icon-*** classes, but rather you need to give your  tag a class of 'fa' and 'fa-search', for instance.

See the example [here](http://fontawesome.io/icon/search/)